# Send email list if cell value is less than percentage spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a script to send a single email with the entire list of rows that are below a certain percentage (column g).

I would like to send date, city and percentage.

I've seen some scripts that send email when a cell has a certain value, but I haven't found anything that lists everything.

I have the following example sheet. Many thanks

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1abdggD73Zb0XmRoFaMx0ssULjtLLTHhFQV3ikbaEK_I/edit#gid=0

I would like to send list with date, city and percentage

Comment: What's keeping you from doing what you want?

Comment: If you want more help we need more information

Comment: I want to send an email with all the information of each column that is below 90%.

All in a single email.